# Want some help understanding this method

Tags: c#, keyedcollection

```
class SetMap : KeyedCollection<Type, object>
{
    public HashSet<T> Use<T>(IEnumerable<T> sourceData)
{
    var set = new HashSet<T>(sourceData);
    if (Contains(typeof(T)))
    {
        Remove(typeof(T));
    }
    Add(set);
    return set;
}

public HashSet<T> Get <T>()
{
    return (HashSet<T>) this[typeof(T)];
}

protected override Type GetKeyForItem(object item)
{
    return item.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();
}
}
```

would anyone clarify this for me pls.  return (HashSet) this[typeof(T)]; with example if possible.
thank you

Comment: Where has your research led you so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return (HashSet) this[typeof(T)];
```

Let me split the statement into parts.

(1) `this[...]` means using the indexer of `this`. And `this` basically means "this object".

(2) The indexer accepts a `Type`. And in this call to the indexer, the argument is `typeof(T)`.

(3) `typeof` gets a `Type` object that corresponds to the type in the `()`. In this case, the generic type parameter `T`. And the indexer returns an `object`.

The parameter (`Type`) and return type (`object`) of the indexer can be inferred from the base type of the class: `KeyedCollection<Type, object>`. I think you can understand this.

(4) The value returned by the indexer gets casted into a `HashSet<T>`. Again, `T` is the generic type argument.

(5) The value gets returned to the caller by the `return` statement.

For more information:

1. Indexers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx
2. Generics: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx
3. Casting: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx\
4. `KeyedCollection`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx
5. `typeof`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx

Comment: thanks for the helpful answer, one more question how do we know that KeyedCollection<Type, object> implements the indexer so that we used "this"? or all collections implement it?

Comment: @Abbas I think so. All `ICollection<T>` implements an indexer that accepts a parameter of type `T`

Answer (score 0):

It is using [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx). A modern programming concept that *makes it possible to design classes and methods that defer the specification of one or more types until the class or method is declared and instantiated by client code.*

In your example it is defining a [hashset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) that can hold any type.

Read the MSDN documentation in the links I've provided and if you have a more specific questions post them here.

Comment: to be specific i don't understand this[typeof(T)]. whats happening here ?

Comment: it is checking the type to see if there is an object of that type (typeof) in the hashset and then if it is it removes it.